# To find probability that after the next 4 home claims and 3 car claims the total size of car claims exceeds the total size of the home claims.

Tags: probability

> Claim sizes on a home insurance policy are normally distributed about a mean of £800 and with
> a standard deviation of £100. Claims sizes on a car insurance policy are normally distributed
> about a mean of £1,200 and with a standard deviation of £300. All claims sizes are assumed to be
> independent.
> To date, there have already been home claims amounting to £800, but no car claims.
> Calculate the probability that after the next 4 home claims and 3 car claims the total size of car
> claims exceeds the total size of the home claims.

I proceeded this way:
Let X be home claims and Y be car claims. so I found P(3Y > 4X+800)

Am i correct? The answer I get like this is 0.3409 but the actual answer is 0.236

Comment: No, your working is not correct and the actual answer is correct. Is this a homework question? If it is, please review the [guidelines on homework questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and edit your question to include your work. For a start, I notice that you have 4X+100, but the question says the total so far for home claims is 800.

Comment: oh I did 4X+800 only wrote that by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT…If $$H\sim N(800,100^2)$$ and $$C\sim N(1200,300^2)$$
Then you are looking for the probability that three independent car claims exceeds four independent house claims by at least $800$, i.e.
$$P(C_1+C_2+C_3>H_1+H_2+H_3+H_4+800)$$

Therefore consider a new normally distributed random variable $X$ where $$X=C_1+C_2+C_3-H_1-H_2-H_3-H_4$$

The mean of $X$ is $3\times1200-4\times800=400$ and the variance of $X$ is $3\times 300^2+4\times 100^2=310000$

Find $$p(X>800)$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: I didn't understand why have you wrote C1 C2 C3 independently like they are identical they follow same distribution so why cant we just write them as 3C

Comment: or okay I got it all claims cant be of same size .

Comment: $3C$ would be a variable representing a triple-sized claim. This would have the same mean as the sum of three claims, but the variance would be 9 times instead of 3 times that of a regular claim

Comment: ya if it was written three times **a** car claim then we would have done 3C